# Calculate the sum $\sum_{k=0}^n \pmatrix{2n \\ 2k} q^k$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Calculate the sum
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \pmatrix{2n \\ 2k} q^k$$
where $q\in\mathbb R$. I have tried to apply the binomial theorem, to get to something like:
$$
(1+a)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}a^k.$$
but I have not been successful.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Note that all the odd terms are missing. One possible way to get rid of the odd terms is:

$$ (1+a)^n + (1-a)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} a^k + \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (-1)^k a^k = \sum_{\substack{k=0\\ k\text{ is even}}}^n \binom{n}{k} 2a^k $$

Answer (score 0):

Let $q$ be any non negative real number. Then

> $$
> \sum_{k=0}^n {2n \choose 2k}q^k =\frac{\left(1+\sqrt{q}\right)^{2n}+\left(1- \sqrt{q}\right)^{2n}}{2}. \tag1
> $$

This just comes from the fact that, as $k>n$, $\displaystyle {2n \choose 2k}=0$, giving
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n {2n \choose 2k}q^k=\sum_{k=0}^{2n} {2n \choose 2k}q^k, \tag2$$ and from the fact that, by the binomial theorem, we have 
$$
 (1+\sqrt{q})^{2n}\! +\! (1-\sqrt{q})^{2n} = \sum_{k=0}^{2n} \binom{2n}{k} \sqrt{q}^k + \sum_{k=0}^{2n} \binom{2n}{k} (-1)^k \sqrt{q}^k=2\sum_{k=0}^{2n} {2n \choose 2k}q^k.
$$

Comment: The last equality makes the substitution $k = 2k'$, so $(2)$ is not really used.

Comment: @MartinR If you do so you will get $\displaystyle \sum_{k'=0}^{n} {2n \choose 4k'}q^{2k'}$, not exactly what we are looking for...

Comment: That's not why I meant, but I may of course be overlooking something. – In $\sum_{k=0}^{2n} \binom{2n}{k} \sqrt{q}^k + \sum_{k=0}^{2n} \binom{2n}{k} (-1)^k \sqrt{q}^k$, only the even $k$ contribute to the sums, so you can replace $k$ by $2k'$ where $k'$ runs from $0$ to $n$.  Then you get $2\sum_{k'=0}^{2n} {2n \choose 2k'}q^{k'}$. – Or why does $\sqrt{q}^k$ become $q^k$ in your last identity?

Comment: ... and I meant $2\sum_{k'=0}^{n} {2n \choose 2k'}q^{k'}$ ...

Comment: @MartinR Please, write **an identity**, then I will show you the point. Thanks.

Comment: $\sum_{k=0}^{2n} \binom{2n}{k} \sqrt{q}^k + \sum_{k=0}^{2n} \binom{2n}{k} (-1)^k \sqrt{q}^k = 2 \sum_{k=0, 2, 4, \ldots}^{2n} \binom{2n}{k} \sqrt{q}^k = 2 \sum_{l=0}^{n} \binom{2n}{l} \sqrt{q}^{2l} =2 \sum_{l=0}^{n} \binom{2n}{l} {q}^l$. – Your result is correct, I am just stating that the fact $\displaystyle {2n \choose 2k}=0$ for $k > n$ is not used at all.

Comment: I don't understand your second equality, it should be $ 2 \sum_{k=0, 2, 4, \ldots}^{2n} \binom{2n}{k} \sqrt{q}^k = 2 \sum_{l=0}^{n} \binom{2n}{2l} \sqrt{q}^{2l}.$ No? Since you put $k=2l$...

Comment: @MartinR Have you seen your mistake? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Sorry for the confusion, that happened when I edited the LaTeX in the comment. So let's try it again: $\sum_{k=0}^{2n} \binom{2n}{k} \sqrt{q}^k + \sum_{k=0}^{2n} \binom{2n}{k} (-1)^k \sqrt{q}^k = 2 \sum_{k=0, 2, 4, \ldots}^{2n} \binom{2n}{k} \sqrt{q}^k = 2 \sum_{l=0}^{n} \binom{2n}{2l} \sqrt{q}^{2l} =2 \sum_{l=0}^{n} \binom{2n}{2l} {q}^l$. – Anyway, the *only thing* I (perhaps badly) tried to express is that ${2n \choose 2k}=0$ for $k > n$ (and therefore your equation $(2)$) is not used at all ...

Comment: @MartinR OK, thank you very much.